# Issues With PHPmyadmin 3.4.9 Export To CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, export-to-csv

Format-specific options

Columns separated with: ,

Columns enclosed with: "

Columns escaped with: \

Lines terminated with: AUTO

Remove carriage return/line feed characters within columns :ticked

When comma symbols are inside text field of a column,which is enclosed by " (quote symbol) , they don't have designated escaped character(in this case ) thus the resulted CSV file is read incorrectly

the problematic field is longtext which can contain any special characters including new line(\n)

base Row example:

```
XXXX | YYYY | ZZZZ | hi i am bla bla <img src = "blabla.com"> , hihi |
```

resulted CSV Example:

```
"xxxx", "YYYY", "ZZZZ", "hi i am bla bla <img src = \"blabla.com\">, hihi"
```

The example should give a clear sight of problem : comma within column-enclosing quote doesn't escape and get counted as a column-separating comma

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

With respect, you misunderstand the rules for escaping CSV columns. When a column's text is enclosed in double quote marks, all characters are allowed in that text, except double quotes themselves. So, there is no need to escape comma characters.

Your example:

```
Raw:  hi i am bla bla <img src = "blabla.com">, hihi

Quoted:  "hi i am bla bla <img src = \"blabla.com\">, hihi"
```

is correct. Reading CSV files with quoted columns is harder than it appears at first glance. In fact, it's a notorious pain in the neck to do right. Wise programmers use a fully-debugged package to do it.

Comment: I solved it... 
It's a problem with CSV Reader, not the file itself. The default setting ignores escape character which consequently makes it ignores quote symbol.

Thx for the answer and you are completely right, it's MUCH harder than I think it is. Another hard lesson learned in a hard way :/